# Dojo scope question for store.query with ItemFileWriteStore

Tags: dojo, scope

I am writing a method to grab the lowest unique id in an ItemFileWriteStore. I have a boolean to tell me when I reach my condition, but I can't get the scope correct.

The function call works as I expect, apart from when newIdOkay is set to true, it is not recognised in the while loop.

Please can you explain why and what I have to do to get this right?

Many thanks

Here is my code:

```
function checkNewId( size ) {
    if( size == 0 ) {
        console.log('found new ID!');
        newIdOkay = true;
    }
 }

function addContentItem( store ) {    
    // New ID 
    var newIdOkay = false;
    var newId = 0;

    while( newIdOkay == false && newId < 8 ) {
        newId++;
        store.fetch({ query: {id:newId}, onBegin: dojo.hitch(this, "checkNewId"),                          
                      start:0, count:0, sync:true });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To understand the reason, you need to have basic understanding of identifier resolution and scope chain in JavaScript. I recommend you to read this article: http://jibbering.com/faq/notes/closures/

Regarding you question, in the function `addContentItem`, the check in the while loop is tested against the identifier `newIdOkay` which is in the of the activation object corresponding to this function execution context. In the function `checkNewId`, the identifier `newIdOkay` you set is in the global object. So these two are not the same one. An easy fix is to move the `newIdOkay` in `addContentItem` function to the global scope.

```
var newIdOkay = false;

function checkNewId( size ) {
    if( size == 0 ) {
        console.log('found new ID!');
        newIdOkay = true;
    }
 }

function addContentItem( store ) {    
    // New ID 

    var newId = 0;

    while( newIdOkay == false && newId < 8 ) {
        newId++;
        store.fetch({ query: {id:newId}, onBegin: dojo.hitch(this, "checkNewId"),                          
                  start:0, count:0, sync:true });
    }
}
```